# Can SQL Server be configured to not silently truncate VARCHAR values?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

In some scenarios like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48043635/sql-server-user-defined-function-to-calculate-age-bracket/48043653#48043653), SQL Server will silently truncate (N)VARCHAR values leading to serious data loss when incorrectly declaring variables.

**Question:** Can SQL Server be configured to not silently truncate VARCHAR values? (and issue an error/raise an exception instead)

Comment: you have to declare your size of the varchar if you are working with variables

Comment: In the link you posted the problem is that someone declare the type as varchar instead of specifying correct max size. So it's not SQL Server error, it's someone that used the dafault 1 by omitting the correct size, and as a result had only 1 character -- exactly because he used varchar = varchar(1)

Comment: The issue I have linked to is only an example. I know about the mistake from the OP, but I am wondering if this could be prevented by using a specific switch (raise an exception when someone tries to insert a large string into a small (n)varchar).

Comment: In a Ruby project backed by SqlServer 2014, I was able to get the server to reject insert or update statements that would have truncated data by changing a connection option with `SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON`.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44855921/238886).  Not adding this as an answer because there are three layers of library between my code and SqlServer, so not sure if that option is a universal fix, or just something that worked for my narrow circumstances.

Comment: @WayneConrad - this is really useful. I will try to see if I can obtain a similar behavior using ADO.NET connector. However, I think this can only prevent `string or binary would be truncated`, not errors related to silently truncation of strings when assigned to variables.

Comment: Related discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628140/sql-server-silently-truncates-varchars-in-stored-procedures).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No there's no way to change this behavior.  But this truncation only happens with variable and parameter assignments, not table inserts.

EG

```
declare @str varchar(8) = 'some very long string'
```

will be silently truncated

but an insert:

```
create table #t(a varchar(8))
insert into #t(a) values('some very long string')
```

will fail with

```
Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 7
String or binary data would be truncated.
```

This is a consequence of TSQL's permissive use of implicit conversions, which is convenient in many cases, but sometimes troublesome.

Comment: Yes, it is correct that it happens only when working with variables. I have fixed the OP. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The Database Engine has some built-in defaults for handling data types.

The definition of the data types `char` and `varchar` is as follows:

> `char [ ( n ) ]` Fixed-length, non-Unicode string data. `n` defines the string length and must be a value from 1 through 8,000. The storage size is `n` bytes. The ISO synonym for char is character.
>
> `varchar [ ( n | max ) ]` Variable-length, non-Unicode string data. `n` defines the string length and can be a value from 1 through 8,000. `max` indicates that the maximum storage size is 2^31-1 bytes (2 GB). The storage size is the actual length of the data entered + 2 bytes. The ISO synonyms for varchar are charvarying or charactervarying.

For `char` and `varchar` the defaults are as follows:

> When **`n` is not specified** in a data definition or variable declaration statement, the **default length is `1`**. When `n` is **not specified when using the CAST and CONVERT** functions, the **default length is `30`**.

If you don't define a length, then SQL Server will do it for you.

#### Reference

- [char and varchar (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql)

Comment: That is correct, but wouldn't declaring the variable as `VARCHAR(8)` and trying to insert a value of something greater than 8 characters also lead to truncation? My problem is preventing the truncation in general, not truncation to one character.

Comment: Yes, it would lead to data truncation. You can't prevent truncation unless ... `1).` you specify `varchar(max)` _but even then data could be truncated by the database limitations_... `2).` you modify your GUI to limit the input ... `3).` you programmatically catch the input before you insert it into the database ... `4).` store the data in external files instead of in a database. A table is generally limited according to the specifications drafted in the Requirements Engineering phase of the project and according to the requirements of the customer/stakeholder.